# Taking a screenshot of only portion of the browser using selenium in VBA | "Selenium VBA"

Tags: vba, selenium

so this one is about taking a screenshot of only a portion of the browser using Selenium in VBA. I saw there is something like

takescreenshot.hieght

takescreenshot.width

but not sure how to use these sub attributes height and width or if they will work.

Plus I have multiple images to save using different filenames automatically. I tried this but it did not work.

```
dim bot as chromedriver, img as selenium.image
bot.get "http:// xxxxxxx.....com"
..
..
for a = 1 to 100
set img = bot.takescreenshot(500)
img.Saveas this workbook.path & " :\" & a & ".jpg"
```

any suggestions please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is unfortunately no built in function to take partial screenshots. However, you might try the following function to get an image of a specific element--please forgive any vb related mistakes I may have made as I rarely use the language.

```
Public Function CaptureElementScreenShot(ByVal element As HTMLElement, ByVal uniqueName As String) As Image
    Dim screenshot As Screenshot = (CType(Me.driver, ITakesScreenshot)).GetScreenshot()
    screenshot.SaveAsFile(filename, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Jpeg)
    Dim img As Image = Bitmap.FromFile(uniqueName)
    Dim rect As Rectangle = New Rectangle()

    If element IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim width As Integer = element.Size.Width
        Dim height As Integer = element.Size.Height
        Dim p As Point = element.Location
        rect = New Rectangle(p.X, p.Y, width, height)
    End If

    Dim bmpImage As Bitmap = New Bitmap(img)
    Dim croppedImage = bmpImage.Clone(rect, bmpImage.PixelFormat)
    Return croppedImage
End Function
```